# Example websites using db4o

Tags: orm, enterprise, db4o, object-oriented-database

I'm very impressed with my initial tests with db4o. However, i'm wondering just how many enterprise class websites are out there powered by db4o, i couldn't see any on the main website?

I can't see any reason why db4o should not be used. There appears to be decent enough support for transactions and ways to handle concurrency for example.

Anyone got a list of websites i could look at?

Comment: From my DB4O searches I see that you did the same thing as me almost a month ago (08/10/05 -> 08/10/23). Any more web-user stories from this month? Since there are no PM's here I would appreciate a line at my.username@gmail.com (replace my username plz).

Answer (score 1):

A particular search engine used to be powered by db4o (I say "used to" because I haven't talked to the author about this since a long time).

http://www.rel8r.com/

The author is Travis Reeder.

Answer (score 1):

See:

http://developer.db4o.com/Projects/html/projectspaces/gaabormarkt.html

Answer (score 0):

Although I cannot see websites specifically, here is a list of Open Source Projects from the db4o website:

http://developer.db4o.com/ProjectSpaces/view.aspx/Open_Source_Products